# How can I relocate or disable the VirtualBox logfile when starting a vm from Vagrant?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

When I run `vagrant up` using VirtualBox as a provider, it creates a logfile called `ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log` in the project root. This causes difficulty with PHPStorm, as it doesn't have an option to exclude individual files from search, only folders.

I would like to have this logfile created in the `_log` directory instead, but I cannot find how to configure its location; there doesn't seem to be anything in the Vagrantfile documentation, and I can't find an option in the VirtualBox GUI.

I've also tried symlinking the file to /dev/null, but VirtualBox refuses to even start if the link is there. I can't simply delete the file while the VM is up, as it holds a lock on it.

A simplified version of the `Vagrantfile` is below:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.disksize.size = "10GB"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    # redacted
  SHELL
end
```

How can I change the log location? Or, if that's possible, how can I prevent it from being generated in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to change the log file location as per [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/eZljy-bddoI). To change the log file location to a folder called /temp relative to my Vagrantfile, I added this to the Vagrantfile (inside the `Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|` - section):

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize [
    "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "file",
    File.join(Dir.pwd, "temp/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log")
  ]
end
```

This seems to override the current location settings. The temp-folder
must already be present.

To completely disable the log file output, follow the recipe from the above link:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
end
```