# VirtualBox called by vagrant - unable to control serial port raw file value

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

OK, I'll explain what the issue is first to be brief, and then explain why it's a problem.

I use Vagrant to start a `bionic64` virtual machine.  When I do a file is created in the root directory named `ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg-console.log`

However in VirtualBox the settings for Serial Ports include the absolute path.  I can `vagrant halt` and change this to

```
./ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg-console-ci4.log
```

but when I `vagrant up`, the settings have reverted and the file name is still the same.  How do I fix this, or what's overriding this?

[image: Default setting including absolute path]

[image: What I would like it to be (but it gets overwritten)]

#### Why This is a Problem

packaging the box and trying to distribute it, that absolute path sticks around and doesn't exist in the target computer.  Makes it impossible to share the box.

#### Oh, and the Vagrantfile..

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # VM Box
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  # Automatic box update checking
  config.vm.box_check_update = true

  # CodeIgniter virtual host
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  # Code Coverage virtual host
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 81, host: 8081, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  # User Guide virtual host
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 82, host: 8082, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  # MySQL server
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3307, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  # PostgreSQL server
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5433, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  # Memcached server
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 11211, host: 11212, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  # Redis server
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6379, host: 6380, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Add "192.168.10.10 ${VIRTUALHOST}" in your host file to access by domain
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.101"

  # Same path set in the $CODEIGNITER_PATH Provision
  # "virtualbox" type allow auto-sync host to guest and guest to host
  # but chmod does not work... tests will fail.
  # Default rsync__args except "--copy-links", to allow phpunit correctly works by symlink
  # Wait, this might be a problem using rsync - I saw a folder that wasn't there till I rebooted
  # config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "rsync", rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--archive", "--delete", "-z"]


  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=757"]


  # Provider-specific configuration
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = false
    # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  # Provision
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASS="password"
    PGSQL_ROOT_PASS="password"
    VIRTUALHOST="localhost"
    CODEIGNITER_PATH="/var/www/codeigniter"
    PHP_VERSION=7.2
    PGSQL_VERSION=10
    #APT_PROXY="192.168.10.1:3142"

    grep -q "127.0.0.1 ${VIRTUALHOST}" /etc/hosts || echo "127.0.0.1 ${VIRTUALHOST}" >> /etc/hosts

    # Creates a swap file if necessary
    RAM=`awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo`
    if [ $RAM -lt 1000000 ] && [ ! -f /swap/swapfile ]; then
        echo "================================================================================"
        echo "Adding swap"
        echo "================================================================================"
        echo "This process may take a few minutes. Please wait..."
        mkdir /swap
        dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile bs=1024 count=1000000
        chmod 600 /swap/swapfile
        mkswap /swap/swapfile
        swapon /swap/swapfile
        echo "/swap/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
        echo "Done."
    fi

    # Prepare to use APT Proxy
    if [ ! -z $APT_PROXY ]; then
        if [ ! -f /etc/apt/sources.list-origin ]; then
            cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list-origin
        fi
        sed -i "s/archive.ubuntu.com/${APT_PROXY}/" /etc/apt/sources.list
        sed -i "s/security.ubuntu.com/${APT_PROXY}/" /etc/apt/sources.list
    fi

    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

    echo "================================================================================"
    echo "Updating and Installing Required Packages"
    echo "================================================================================"

    apt-get update

    debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}"
    debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}"

    apt-get install -y \
    php$PHP_VERSION apache2 composer \
    php-intl php-mbstring php-xml php-zip php-xdebug \
    php-mysql mysql-server mysql-client \
    php-pgsql postgresql-$PGSQL_VERSION \
    php-sqlite3 sqlite3 \
    php-memcached memcached \
    php-redis redis-server \
    php-curl curl \
    php-gd php-imagick \
    python-pip

    pip install sphinx sphinxcontrib-phpdomain

    apt-get autoclean

    echo "================================================================================"
    echo "Preparing User Guide"
    echo "================================================================================"

    cd "${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/user_guide_src/cilexer"
    python setup.py install
    cd ..
    make html

    echo "================================================================================"
    echo "Configuring Databases"
    echo "================================================================================"

    sed -i "s/^bind-address/#bind-address/" /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS codeigniter COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
    UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE user='root';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS
    systemctl restart mysql

    sed -i "s/^#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/" /etc/postgresql/$PGSQL_VERSION/main/postgresql.conf
    grep -q "host    all             root            all                     md5" /etc/postgresql/$PGSQL_VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf || echo "host    all             root            all                     md5" >> /etc/postgresql/$PGSQL_VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf
    sudo -u postgres psql -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='root'" | grep -q 1 || sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE ROLE root WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN"
    sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER ROLE root WITH PASSWORD '${PGSQL_ROOT_PASS}'"
    sudo -u postgres psql -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='codeigniter'" | grep -q 1 ||sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE codeigniter"
    sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE codeigniter TO root"
    systemctl restart postgresql

    echo "================================================================================"
    echo "Configuring Memcached and Redis"
    echo "================================================================================"

    sed -i "s/^bind 127.0.0.1/#bind 127.0.0.1/" /etc/redis/redis.conf
    sed -i "s/^protected-mode yes/protected-mode no/" /etc/redis/redis.conf
    sed -i "s/^-l 127.0.0.1/#-l 127.0.0.1/" /etc/memcached.conf
    systemctl restart redis
    systemctl restart memcached

    echo "================================================================================"
    echo "Configuring Virtual Hosts"
    echo "================================================================================"

    mkdir -p "${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/build/coverage-html"
    mkdir -p "${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/public"
    mkdir -p "${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/user_guide_src/build/html"
    mkdir -p "${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/writable/apache"
    chown -R vagrant:vagrant $CODEIGNITER_PATH

    # Creates a symlink in the user home
    if [ ! -d /home/vagrant/codeigniter ]; then
        ln -s $CODEIGNITER_PATH /home/vagrant/codeigniter
    fi

    sed -i "s/APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data/APACHE_RUN_USER=vagrant/" /etc/apache2/envvars
    sed -i "s/APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data/APACHE_RUN_GROUP=vagrant/" /etc/apache2/envvars
    grep -q "Listen 81" /etc/apache2/ports.conf || sed -i "s/^Listen 80/Listen 80\\nListen 81\\nListen 82/" /etc/apache2/ports.conf
    sed -i "s/^display_errors = Off/display_errors = On/" /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
    sed -i "s/^display_startup_errors = Off/display_startup_errors = On/" /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

    echo "ServerName ${VIRTUALHOST}
<Directory ${CODEIGNITER_PATH}>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin vagrant@localhost
    DocumentRoot ${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/public
    ErrorLog  ${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/writable/apache/error.log
    CustomLog ${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/writable/apache/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot ${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/build/coverage-html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot ${CODEIGNITER_PATH}/user_guide_src/build/html
</VirtualHost>
" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/codeigniter.conf

    a2enmod rewrite
    a2dissite 000-default.conf
    a2ensite codeigniter.conf
    systemctl restart apache2

    echo "================================================================================"
    echo "Services Status"
    echo "================================================================================"
    service --status-all

  SHELL
end
```

Comment: In case you haven't seen [this](https://superuser.com/a/1395394/291007), maybe it is helpful to you? In my case, the problem is that vagrant is setting a WSL linux-style path there instead of the windows path, so it's not helping for me because it will end up as a linux-style path again.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer and a sequence for this that solves the problem.

- The absolute path for the Serial Port RawFile #0 that I can't change, I can't change when the VM is running because VirtualBox won't allow that
- I can change it when it's NOT running in VirtualBox, but if **VAGRANT** starts the VM, it automatically overrides this value to the `Vagrantfile` root as an absolute path
- This makes sense for clarity but it also stays with the box when I do `vagrant package` on a running box (which I believe it has to be running).

The solution is as follows:

- with the VM not running, open VirtualBox, and change the file path and name to `./your-file-name`
- then start the VM in VirtualBox instead of using `vagrant up`
- (optional) `vagrant ssh` into the box if you need to from the command line to set any needed running state.
- log out and run `vagrant package`.  The file path and name will export as what you named it!

This story doesn't exactly end perfectly, as I wondered where my `./my-custom-file` would be located.  Turns out for my Vagrant install, in Vagrant's brains that's in the `/Applications` folder.  I would have thought the path would be in the Vagrant program's root or a subfolder, or in the folder for the specific box.  Probably there is a `$PATH` setting you can use, but this works for now (between Macs, and probably in Windows as well).